# From $f(x,y)=g(3x-4y)$ and $f(x,0)=\sin x$ for all $x$, how can I find $f(x,y)$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I found 
$f(x,y)=g(3x-4y)$ and $f(x,0)=\sin x$ for all $x$. How can I find $f(x,y)$?

It seems like $g(3x)=\sin x$ for all $x$. But how can I find $g(3x-4y)$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$g(3x) = \sin x \implies g(3x-4y) = \sin \frac{3x-4y}3$$

Answer (score 1):

You need a formula for $g$.  You have  $g(3x)=\sin x$.

Introduce $z = 3x$ here, so that this formula reads as $g(z) = \sin(z/3)$.

Now you have a formula for $g$, and you can plug anything you want for $z$. In particular, 
you can plug $z=3x−4y$ and obtain the solution.